# What is crusty loaf bread?

Tags: bread

I have a recipe for garlic crack bread (pull apart bread) that calls for a crusty loaf, preferably sourdough or Vienna. I have looked in the bakery sections and can not find. Is there possibly a different name I should be looking for?

Comment: Its not a technical name for a bread, its a descriptive name.

Answer (score 2):

It's any loaf with a crispy crust. There's not much more to it than that. If you can't find sourdough or Vienna, just use a standard white loaf with a crisp crust.

Comment: The only thing I'd add is that 'crusty' doesn't just imply texture but substance. I was taught a crusty loaf of bread should have a thump to it when you knock on it. The meaning seems largely colloquial so...